# std move vectors float[3] into vector class x,y,z

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector of 3 values in two different forms, and I would like to pass from one to the other:

- a `std::vector< float[3] >`, `std::vector< std::vector<float> >` or even `float[][3]` if needed (that's the part I can change)
- a `std::vector` of the `color` class

Let's work with these classes:

```
class color{
    float x,y,z;
    //some methods but no other member
}
```

What I would like to do:

```
std::vector<float[3]> myVector; // already allocated and filled
std::vector<color> cv = std::move( myVector ); // of course does not compile
```

My issue is that I didn't figure out how to convert one to the other without having to reallocate memory.
I can convert a `float[3]` into `color` using `static_cast` but it seems it does not work for a vector.

I would like not to iterate over the whole array and simply move the data from `myVector` inside the `cv` vector. I thought converting the pointer of `myVector` to `void*` and then to `color3*` could work, but I didn't succeed.

Ideas?

Comment: *I can convert a float[3] into color using static_cast* No you can't. If you want to move data, it needs to be heap allocated and for 3 floats it's probably not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a `std::vector<float[3]>` at all prior to C++20 because `float[3]` didn't meet the requirements of the value type that `std::vector` had. Since C++20 it technically is allowed, but is still not useful in practice since any member function that adds elements does still have requirements not satisfied by arrays.

Let's assume that you were asking a similar question where you have two different classes, where one is `color` and the other contains an array as a member. Such as `std::array<float, 3>`.

> I would like not to iterate over the whole array and simply move the data from myVector inside the cv vector.

There is simply no way to avoid that. The **only** way to "move" data into a vector without iteration is to move from another vector of the **same** type. That singular case doesn't apply to your case of different types, so you must have iteration. You don't necessarily need to write the loop yourself, as you may use a standard algorithm instead.  Here is an example using standard ranges:

```
std::vector<std::array<float,3>> myVector; // already allocated and filled
std::vector<color> cv;
auto arr_to_color = [](const std::array<float,3>& arr){
    // assuming such constructor exists
    return color(
        arr[0],
        arr[1],
        arr[2]);
};
std::ranges::transform(
    myVector,
    std::back_inserter(cv),
    arr_to_color);
```

Comment: I think it's reasonable to try to avoid the copy, maybe we can try it with customized allocators.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin You can avoid a copy by starting with a `std::vector<color>` in the first place, or by never converting to `std::vector<color>`.

Comment: The actual memory is the same though, no? In memory, with float=4B I would have 12B of color, x,y,z and for float[3], or std::array<float,3>, it would be the same, am I wrong there? Isn't it possible to make it a void* then?

Comment: @Patafikss You can point at it with a `void*`. But doing so won't help you create a `std::vector<color>`.

Comment: I see, it would still be a copy. I guess there's no way round it then

Comment: Note: std::ranges requires g++10 at least, c++20